# .xml views alignment

Tags: android, xml

I have a problem and I really don't know now how to deal with it.This is my .xml file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlActivityDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:overScrollMode="always" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibStartTrip"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/car" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStartTrip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ibStartTrip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibStartActivity"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ibStartTrip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibStartTrip"
        android:src="@drawable/tools" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStartActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ibStartActivity"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibEndActivity"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ibStartActivity"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibStartActivity"
        android:src="@drawable/finish" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEndActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ibEndActivity"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ibEndActivity"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayoutInfo"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvStartActivity"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/imageView1"
               android:layout_width="24dp"
               android:layout_height="24dp"
               android:layout_column="0"
               android:src="@drawable/number" />            
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvActivityIdValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16dp" />             
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:src="@drawable/activity_type" />                
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvActivityTypeValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16dp" />      
         </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:src="@drawable/site" />                      
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSiteNameValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                android:textSize="16dp" />                  
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:src="@drawable/brand" />                    
            <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/tvBrandValue"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_column="1"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                  android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                  android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                  android:textSize="16dp" />                    
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:src="@drawable/subject" />          
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSubjectValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                android:textSize="16dp" />                               
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                  android:layout_width="24dp"
                  android:layout_height="24dp"
                  android:layout_column="0"
                  android:src="@drawable/text" />           
            <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/tvTextValue"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_column="1"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                  android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssss"
                  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:textSize="16dp"
                  android:width="0dip" />            
        </TableRow>
         </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayoutAssets"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutInfo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>

     </TableLayout>

     <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutAssets"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">     

                 <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/myGallery"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >                            
                 </LinearLayout>             
         </HorizontalScrollView>   

         <ProgressBar
             android:id="@+id/progressBarAttachment"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutAssets"
             android:visibility="gone" 
                />

             <ImageButton 
               android:id="@+id/ibAddImage"  
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollImageView"
               android:src="@drawable/add_button"
               android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As you can see I have 3 image buttons.Under them a table layout with 6 rows.After that another table layout which is populated dynamically and under that a horizontal scroll view which is populated dynamically with pictures,and an image button for adding new pictures.

Now,my problem is that every time i open the activity,after the pictures are loaded in the horizontal scroll view, the last row from my first table layout is disappearing(is not disappearing completely  but its width is getting very small and it only fits one letter per row).
I think that after the pictures are loaded the entire layout is redrawing itself and the first table doesn't maintain his properties(the "weight" property also does't apply anymore after the pictures are loaded).I could really use some help.
 Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thx.

Comment: I would advise you to cleanup the layout file and not put every layout attribute that you can find. Remove the `layout_weights` from all the elements in the rows in the first `TableLayout` and add the attribute `android:stretchColumns="1"` to the first `TableLayout` and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: the property "stretchColumns" works fine,but my problem remains.everything looks fine until my asynctask loads the pictures.After that the "stretchColumns" property does't apply anymore and  the last two rows from the first table layout displays only one character per line.

Comment: i've also tried to put the second table layout and the horizontalScrollView in another RelativeLayout,but still doesn't work.I's very frustrating

Comment: Why do you use the `android:width="0dip"` property? Remove it from the `TextView` in the last `TableRow` from the `tableLayoutInfo` `TableLayout` and see how the layout behaves.

Comment: I've posted an answer if you would like to accept it so the question would become answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the `android:width` attribute on the last `TextView`. Remove it and the `TextViews` should behave.